# Let $f(x) = x^2 - 4x - 12$ prove that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on the set $[-2,∞)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

so I know that to show this is NOT uniformly continuous then I need to show that $\exists \epsilon>0$ $\forall \delta>0 \exists x,y\in [-2,\infty)$ such that $(|x-y|<\delta ~~\&~~ |f(x) - f(y)|≥\epsilon)$

so here is what I have so far, I broke down the $|f(x)-f(y)|$ equation to get the following
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|& = |x^2 - 4x - 12 - (y^2 - 4y - 12)|\\& = |x^2 - 4x - y^2 + 4y|\\& = |(X^2 - y^2) - (4x-4y)| \\&= |(x+y)(x-y) - 4(x-y)| \\&= |(x-y)(x+y-4)|\\&= |x-y|\times|x+y-4|
\end{align}
I had a problem on my homework similar to this earlier, so I know the algebra is correct.

So here is what I was thinking, so I'll let $\epsilon = 1.$ For all $\delta>0,$ let $y = x + \delta/2,$ so $|x-y| = |x - x + \delta/2| = d/2 < d.$ So, I showed $|x-y|< \delta$ but now I am having trouble trying to show that $|f(x) - f(y)|≥ 1 = \epsilon.$

so I know we have $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y|∙|x+y-4|= \delta/2∙|x + x + \delta/2 - 4|$ (since $y = x + \delta/2$) but I am not sure what to do from here.

I feel like I'm so close, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+x^{-1})-f(x)=2\ne0$$

Answer (score 0):

You rightly point out that we need to show that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$, there are $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$.

In fact, we can show something stronger: for **all** $\epsilon>0$, it is true that  for all $\delta>0$, there are $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$.

So let some arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ be given. As you have shown, we have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y||x+y-4|.
$$
For any $\delta>0$, there is $N>0$ so large that $N\delta>\epsilon$. Let $x=N+2+\delta/2$ and $y=N+2+\delta$. Then
$$
|x-y|=\delta/2<\delta\quad\text{and}\quad|x-y||x+y-4|>(\delta/2)2N=\delta N>\epsilon.
$$

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much! :)